# counting leap years between 2 dates using conditional statements & while loops JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have a larger function that is calculating the interval of time between an input year, month and day and now in JavaScript. In this part of my function, I'm testing to see which year is larger (because the way it's designed, it can take a date either from the past or in the future and can calculate the interval of time)... In the beginning, I calculated the interval of time in UTC then converted it to days and eventually I have to return the interval in years, months and days again so convert the interval again.
In this section, I'm trying to get an accurate count of how many leap years occurred during the time span but because the input date could be in the future or past, I've set up conditional statements to see which date is bigger so I can iterate through the timespan. Anyways, i'm having alot of problems creating this function (which is just a small part of my larger function) to test for leap year and add to the leap year count (which I want returned so I can accurately convert the interval in days to years, months and days). I feel like my syntax with all of these conditional statements is a little off (I really just started programming in JavaScript a couple months ago) & I don't know how to assign the variable "year" in the leap year algorithm test before that test so I can test it since I want year to be all the years in between the 2 years (yearNow and yearThen)... Anyways, Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
var leapYear = function (inputYear, inputMonth, inputDay) {
  var now = new Date();
  var yearNow= now.getFullYear();
  var then = new Date(inputYear, (inputMonth-1), inputDay);
  var yearThen = then.getFullYear;
  var leapYearCount = 0;
  var beginYear = 0;
  if (yearNow < yearThen)
  beginYear = yearNow;
  while (beginYear < yearThen) {
  if ((year & 3) === 0 && ((year % 25) !== 0 || (year & 15) === 0))
    leapYearCount += 1;
    beginYear++;
  }
  if (yearThen < yearNow)
  beginYear = yearThen;
  while (beginYear < yearNow) {
  if ((year & 3) === 0 && ((year % 25) !== 0 || (year & 15) === 0))
    leapYearCount += 1;
    beginYear++;
  }
  return leapYearCount;
};
```

Edit** I tried setting what's here as "year" as "beginYear" but ended up getting 489 leap years between 2005 and now which is definitely Not correct- I feel like I might be doing something else Wrong in this function besides just not assigning "year" but I'm not sure what... Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use paragraphs please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will count your leapyears, keep in mind it ll count the current year also as leap year if its a leap year and also the starting year as a leap year if its a leap year.

```js
    var countLeapYears = function(y,m,d){
        var yearNow = new Date().getFullYear(),
            yearThen = y,
            beginYear = 0,
            endYear = 0,
            leapYearCount = 0;
  
        var isLeapYear = function(year){
          return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
        }
  
        if(yearNow < y){
           beginYear = yearNow;
           endYear = y;
        }else if(yearNow > y){
           beginYear = y;
           endYear = yearNow;
        }else if(yearNow == y){
           beginYear = y;
           endYear = y;
        }
 
        for(i = beginYear; i <= endYear; i++){
          if(isLeapYear(i)){
            leapYearCount++;
          }
        }
  
        return leapYearCount;
    }

    console.log(countLeapYears(2005,10,12)); // 3
    console.log(countLeapYears(2020,10,12)); // 2
    console.log(countLeapYears(2016,10,12)); // 1
```

Comment: wow, thank you @Harry Bomrah  (I never know if there's a space in the usernames here). It's a rlly smart solution to separate it out into another function. Also, I just had the realization that maybe I needed to do a For loop instead of While loops {it's why I was checking back here ;-) }- I was going to edit my question to ask "do u think I need a for loop" - thank you! I really just started learning JS so it's all a learning process- thank you so much- this has helped me alot- now I have 2 convert it all from days to days, months & years & testing 4 leap years- Thanks!!!

Comment: Thank U so much- this is designed so much better than the way I had it- Thank You so much @HarryBomrah!

Comment: @TamaraFrankel no problem.. I am glad i could help. :)

Comment: @TamaraFrankel if you like the answer, you can accept this answer as your accepted answer so that people in future will know that this question has been solved. Thanks

Comment: hey @Harry Bomrah - how do I officially post your answer as your answer? (I tried sharing the link but it wouldn't let me) - thanks! :-)

Comment: I think I just figured it out @Harry Bomrah, I just pressed the check icon, (duh ;-) ) ... thanks 4 your help- I'm having all types of problems creating a dictionary of my values from then converting my interval in days in days, months & years right now, ach! But this helped me alot- Thanks! Hope u have a lovely day!

Comment: No problem at all.. and I hope u too 've a lovely day :)

Comment: Thanks @Harry Bomrah! I'm working on this actually http://stackoverflow.com/q/35187290/5666784 he he he ;-) but u helped alot!

Comment: Thank You @Harry Bomrah! Hope u r having a great night! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A shorter and faster method to count the number of leap years between 2 years can be achieved by first aligning the years to a boundary of 4 (up and down) and then looping in 4's and checking if a leap year but without the need to check for `year MOD 4` and only for `year MOD 100 and 400`.

This gives a much faster result for large number of year range.

Here is a short function with test examples.

```js
function countLeapYears(yStart, yEnd) {
yEnd   = Math.floor(yEnd/4)*4;
yStart = Math.ceil(yStart/4)*4;
let leaps=0;
while (yStart <= yEnd) {
    (yStart % 100 || !(yStart % 400)) && leaps++;
    yStart +=4;
}
return leaps;
}


//========= tests ==================

console.log(countLeapYears(1,1));       // 0
console.log(countLeapYears(4,4));       // 1
console.log(countLeapYears(2023,2023)); // 0
console.log(countLeapYears(1,2024));    // 491
console.log(countLeapYears(1,30000));   // 7275
console.log(countLeapYears(1,300000));  // 72750
console.log(countLeapYears(2005,2024)); // 5
console.log(countLeapYears(2020,2024)); // 2
console.log(countLeapYears(2016,2024)); // 3
console.log(countLeapYears(2024,2024)); // 1
```